# How to graph a specified range with VBScript

Tags: excel, graph, vbscript

I have an excel sheet with 5 columns in it. I want to use a VBScript to graph data only from columns A, D, and E.

Currently, using the code below, I am getting all 5 columns graphed. Please advise and thanks in advance.

```
With .ActiveChart
 .SetSourceData(Source:=objXLSWorkSheet.Range("A:A" & LastRowofA, "D:D" & LastRowOfD, "E:E" & LastRowOfE))
End With
```

Comment: Named arguments such `Source:=` won't work in VBS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Union` method to create the necessary range:

```
With .ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData .Application.Union(objXLSWorkSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRowofA), objXLSWorkSheet.Range("D1:D" & LastRowOfD), objXLSWorkSheet.Range("E1:E" & LastRowOfE))
End With
```

Comment: Thank you @omegastripes. I surprisingly got it to work with Source:= on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. Below is my code:
    With objXLSWorkSheet
           objExcel.ActiveChart.SetSourceData(Source:=.Application.Union(ObjXLSWorkSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRowOfA), objXLSWorkSheet.Range("D1:D" & LastRowOfD")))
    End with

Comment: @user3681286 You are working with VBScript in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 environment 0_o ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  'objWS = Objet worksheet ("Name"). objExcel = object Excel 
  =>CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      'Use this to select your specific range
      With objWS
        Set xlRange = objExcel.Union(.Range("B1:B5"), .Range("D1:D5"))
      End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below code part to generate a chart with vbscript:

```
objWS = Objet worksheet ("Name"). objExcel = object Excel =>CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 'Use this to select your specific range
 With objWS
Set xlRange = objExcel.Union(.Range("B1:B5"), .Range("D1:D5"))
End With


With GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
 'This code is using to SetSourceData with a specific range  
 objExcel.ActiveChart.SetSourceData xlRange
End With
```